# Make MongoDB RegexFindAll retrieve the line number of match

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB RegexFindAll ouptuts idx, which is the character position in the full string

```
[ { "match" : <string>, "idx" : <num>, "captures" : <array of strings> }, ... ]
```

My documents are song lyrics, so basically lines separated by breaks \n

Is there a way to retrieve something like a line_idx (position in term of lines) ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you determine that the input string in your document has line(s)?

Comment: With line breaks \n

Comment: My documents are actually song lyrics

Comment: Then you can split (`$split`) the string based upon that character (the line break) - that will give you the lines -  as an array of string lines. Then iterate the array and search.